# Use different theme depending on if device is android tablet or phone

Tags: android

I was wondering how I can change the theme of an activity depending on if the device is a tablet or a phone. I have a settings activity that has a `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` theme to it. On the tablet I'd love the theme of this activity to be something like `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`

I chose the theme of the activity in the Manifest.xml file, but as I can see there is no tablet version of this manifest file?

How can I change the theme for this activity? I might also change the theme for some other activities as well to hide the action bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set it dynamically inside each activity like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // ...

    // Call setTheme before creation of any(!) View.

    if(isTablet()) {
        setTheme(android.R.style.Black);
    }
    else {
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);
    }     
    // ...

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Now you need  `isTablet` method but it is a bit difficult to detect device type. Here is a method I found online, it checks the screen size and if the screen is big it assumes current device is a tablet.:

```
public boolean isTablet() {
    try {
        // Compute screen size
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;
        float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;
        double size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) +
                                Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));
        // Tablet devices should have a screen size greater than 6 inches
        return size >= 6;
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        Log.error(TAG_LOG, "Failed to compute screen size", t);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can describe a custom theme (which might simply point to a default theme) in a s[tyle resource file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), and then reference that theme in the Manifest.

Then, you could provide [alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) based on some criteria (just like with drawables of different density, but now you would specify minimum screen size or API level for example).

Manifext:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
```

res/values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The main problem is that I want just on specific Activity to be either a dialog or a fullscreen activity based on if the device is a tablet or not. On the phone the activity would be in a tab bar, on the tablet it's a dialog.
With your solution I can't see how I could accomplish that.

Comment: @Georg: You may try to specify the android:theme for the specific <activity/> element.

Comment: You mean I should to a Theme for each activity and "override" the ones I need for the tablet in the values-xlarge/style.xml?

Comment: @Georg: That sounds an option, your choice to go code or xml.

Comment: I agree with @Georg you can use a combination of api version and screensize aswell, eg. values-v11-xlarge