# Changing an item of style in program in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

I have a styles.xml with this codes:

```
<resources>
     <style name="general_font" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also I have a layout(general_layout.xml) which includes a textview

```
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:text="@string/text1"
   style="@style/general_font"/>
```

Now , In my activity , before content is ready , I want to change textSize in general_font style according to screen height.

So this is my activity class :

```
public class GeneralActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            scaleTextSize(getHeightOfScreen());
            setContentView(R.layout.general_layout);

    }

    private int getHeightOfScreen(){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        return metrics.heightPixels;
    }

    public void scaleTextSize(int height){

        if(height<=320){
            // Change textSize item of general_font style
        }
        else if(height<=480){
            // Change textSize item of general_font style
        }
        else if(height<=800){
            // Change textSize item of general_font style
        }
        else{
            // Change textSize item of general_font style
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible ?? Thanks all advices..

Comment: I would create different styles for different screen sizes and use the styles in the layout files (/res/layout). Differ the layout files as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for comment.Yeah , but There is on thing that I didnt mention.In layout I have 8 textView.I want all textview styles source from just one style.If I create different styles , Should I iterate all textviews to setStyle Right ? I dont want to iterate all textviews , I want change just one item and all textviews take this feature.

Comment: If you dont want to do too much, then use a theme for each screen layout you need. The theme is for your whole application/activity. The theme defining styles would be in the /res/values folders. For instance /res/values-h800dp. See this question for a similar problem as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148749/ /use-different-theme-depending-on-if-device-is-android-tablet-or-phone. I do no have experience doing it manually in code. Thats why my answer is in the comments.

Comment: I got it clearly now.I create different themes which includes textSize attribute for this activity.According to height I set a theme to the activity.It works thank you very much

Comment: I am glad, that I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary answer from our discussion in the comments:

I would create different styles for different screen sizes and use the styles in the layout files (/res/layout). Differ the layout files as described here: [Android Developer Docs about Supporting multiple screensizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

If you dont want to do too much, then use a theme for each screen layout you need. The theme is for your whole application/activity. The theme defining styles would be in the /res/values folders. For instance /res/values-h800dp. See this question for a similar problem as yours: [Use different theme depending on if device is android tablet or phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148749%20/use-different-theme-depending-on-if-device-is-android-tablet-or-phone). 
I don't have experience doing it manually in code. Thats why my answer was initially in the comments.